# How to use scroll root?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know about roof of scroll using jquery.
How to use roof of scroll??
or It is ok that end of scroll move to start of scroll edge.
How to solve this problem.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollTop demo</title>
  <style>
  div.demo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }

  </style>
  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo" id="divDemo">
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li id="li5">5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#divDemo").scrollTop(1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my code. Thanks any reply for my question.

Comment: What do you mean by roof of scroll?

Comment: I think you want to scroll to very top so use scrollTop(0);

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the top of root of the page

```
$("#divDemo").scrollTop(0);
```